# How to add space between subheader contents in Material UI cardHeader?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This question is specific to subheader prop of material ui cardheader. This is not about how to insert space in javascript variable or in JSX.

The code below only results in one space before and after the period. I want to include more spaces or a material ui icon in between.

```
subheader={getDateMonYear(post.createdAt, "MonD") + "    .    " + post.readTime + " min read"}
```

replacing `.` with `AvTimerSharpIcon` give me a result with object.

```
Oct 22 [object Object] 1  min read
```

Span is treated as [object]`<span>   <span>` is output as object.

`&nbsp;` if within quotes outputs as `&nbsp;` and if outside quotes not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whiteSpace: "break-spaces"`

```
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customCardHeader: {
    whiteSpace: "break-spaces"
  }
});

function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <CardHeader
      classes={{ root: classes.customCardHeader }}
      subheader={"foo     bar"}
    />
```

Output would be `foo     bar`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/#props), CardHeader's subheader can be a node.

So, You can pass in any react component and style that component as needed.

```
  <CardHeader
    title="Something"
    subheader={<Typography>foo <span> <FavoriteIcon/> </span>   bar</Typography>}
  />
```

Here's a [sandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bogdan-3fz0x) for reference

Comment: `subheader={<Typography>{getDateMonYear(post......` did not make any difference - same result

Comment: I'm not saying you can't pass in a string, if you want to style that node then you can pass in a node, style the node as needed, heres a sandbox of this working. https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bogdan-3fz0x